# Fetch list of appointments and in turn all associated notes in single query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, orm

I'm trying to fetch a list of appointments, as well as all the notes associated with each appointment, in a way that PHP can then interface with.

Ideally, it should be something like:

```
SELECT Appointment, GROUP_AS_OBJECT(SELECT Note FROM notes WHERE notes.appointmentID = appointments.appointmentID) FROM appointments
```

The ideal result would be something like

```
|--Appointment--|------------------------Note---------------------------|
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Something     | Object["Some Note", "Some Other Note", "Another Note"]|
| Something Else| Object["Other note", "Other Note", "another Note"]    |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So that I can then (Hopefully?) interact with the resulting normal results and object via PHP. It all needs to be done in a single query though, so I'm wondering if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to come up with a vanilla, single query solution, by using GROUP_CONCAT with a custom delimiter (As the standard "," would have caused problems).

```
SELECT Appointment, GROUP_CONCAT(Note SEPARATOR '###') AS Notes FROM Appointments LEFT JOIN notes ON Notes.AppointmentID = Appointments.AppointmentID GROUP BY Notes.AppointmentID
```

Thanks for your help :)!

Comment: One problem I have found with this however, is that it only enables the return of a single column from the Notes table, whereas multiple may be required (Such as who made the note, when it was made etc.), making returning an object once again more attractive...

Comment: Hey, that's cheating! You wanted an object ;-)

Comment: I'd still rather an object solution, but it needs to be vanilla :(!

Comment: Vanilla means no libraries, just core PHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is called ORM, Object relation mapping.
In Java, such ORM API would be JPA.

I believe there are few ORM frameworks in PHP as well.

Check the [Doctrine project](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the info! If possible, I'm after a vanilla solution, do you know if one exists? I'm reluctant to add any frameworks or plugins that are not already implemented (Only jQuery currently is), so if additional frameworks are a necessity, I may be better simply querying the appointments, and then querying the related notes for each appointment separately?